# How to access the keys of a Hashmap and compare them with a predetermined value?

Tags: java, hashmap, unique

I have this Hashmap:

```
HashMap<String, Student> students = new HashMap<String, Student>();
```

After getting 2 String values from the user input (sNo, name) I have been able to put these into the hashmap as such:

```
students.put(sNo, new Student(sNo, name));
```

My problem is, each time I run through this process I want to be able to check the Hashmap key to make sure the input sNo is not the same as one already previously used.

I tried `if(sNo == students.keySet())` but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you did is compare if lets say 5 (sNo) is the same as an object (keySet()). You will always fail this condition. What you're looking for is query the keySet if it contains your sNo value.

```
if (students.keySet().has(sNo))
```

Map provides a shortcut for this in this way:

```
if (students.containsKey(sNo))
```

Also, just as a sidenote, in Java, we write this:

```
Map<Integer, Student> students = new HashMap<>();
```

The above code tells, that the students variable is a Map with Integer as the key and Student as the value. The actual map implementation is unknown and you shouldn't really care about it. Then you create a HashMap which is an actual implementation of the Map interface and using the so called diamond operator <> you tell the compiler that the key and value is the same generic as the one in the declaration of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a loop to compare with all keys currently in your hashmap, one at a time. That way you compare sNo with key1, then sNo with key2, etc. The way you're trying now,

```
(sNo == students.keySet())
```

tries to compare one key with an entire set of keys, which doesn't make sense to the computer. When you compare "things", both "things" need to be the same type, in this case type "String". The syntax for the loop is

```
for(String s: students.keySet()){
//body
}
```

This for loop means "for EACH string in the keyset...(body: compare sNo with s)" Then inside the body you would make the comparison.

IMPORTANT!: You shouldn't compare strings with "==", you should compare them with .equals(). For example, don't do

```
if(sNo == s)
```

but rather

```
if(sNo.equals(s))
```

If you're wondering where i got the s, look inside the for loop. For each String in the keyset, it is assigned to the s variable. Now that you have the for loop, make the comparison between each string in the keyset, and your current key sNo.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to ensure that the key is not already present in the `HashMap` when inserting it, you can use the [`putIfAbsent(K key, V value)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) method:

```
Student s = students.putIfAbsent(sNo, new Student(sNo, name));
```

If the entry already existed, it is returned by the method, else the method inserts the entry in the map and returns `null`:

```
if (s != null) {
    System.out.println("Student "+s.getSno()+" already exists");
}
```